# Regex validation for Hungarian names

Tags: regex, validation

I have made my regex name validation like this (for Hungarian names):

```
/^([A-Z]{1}[a-z áéúőóüö.]{1,}){2,}$/
```

My only problem that is that it accepts more than just 1 space, which I shouldn't allow.

Any idea how could i fix this?

Comment: can you share some examples?

Comment: Hm, it looks like commenting filters out more than 1 space.
So 'John Doe' would be valid, or 'John T. Doe' with 1 space between the words. But if more than 1 space represented between the words would be not valid. The 'áéúőóüö' letters represent the special hungarian letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  space out of character class and add it outside

because `[a-z áéúőóüö.]{1,}` mean match one or more characters represented inside `[]` which will also match any number of spaces as well

you can use [`^([A-Z]([a-záéúőóüö.]{1,}\s?)){2,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/4llP9w/5) to allow only one space.

Improvement for readability : `[A-Z]{1}` is equal to `[A-Z]` so remove unnecessary `{1}` and `{1,}` can simply be `+`

so a concise solution would be [`^([A-Z]([a-záéúőóüö.]+\s?)){2,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/UEIjLN/1)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

*I lost my right to comment because I threw away my rep as bounty, for science, so I I'll post as answer for now and delete it later :D*

small side-note:
There are Hungarian names like Ágnes, Ági, Ákos, Árpád, Ödön, Örs, etc.

Your `[A-Z]` doesn't cover their first letter, so maybe include the uppercase variants of the Hungarian letters in there as well :)

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I noticed that later, but fix this wasn't a big problem. My final regex got to be that: `/^([A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ]([a-záéúőóüöí.]+\s?)){2,}$/`